# NameError (solidity, brownie, python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a deploy script in Python (below) to deploy a smart contract using Brownie. When I compile I get an error that MockV3Aggregator is not defined. I have already created a file called MockV3Aggregator and put the correct code into it and put it in the contracts module.

It works fine to incorporate FundMe.sol from the contracts module so why not MockV3Aggregator.sol?

```
from brownie import FundMe, network, config, MockV3Aggregator
from scripts import helpfulscripts

def deploy_fund_me():
    account  = helpfulscripts.get_account()

    if network.show_active() != "development":
        #add addresses for different networks in config
        price_feed_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["eth_usd_price_feed"]

    else:
        print("deploying mocks")
        mock_aggregator = Mock3Aggregator.deploy(18, 2000000000000000000, {"from": account})
        price_feed_address = mock_aggregator.address
        print("mock deployed")

    fund_me = FundMe.deploy(price_feed_address, {"from": account})
    print(fund_me.address)



def main():
    deploy_fund_me()
```